# How to convert json to old ruby hash object and migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an api definition in json and I want to convert that to an old ruby hash representation like :

```
{:hello => 'there', ....}
```

Actually I want to use that with a create() statement really to add objects to db based on that definition.

I do want to use => because I am very used to it and frankly like it much more than the :

Is there also a tool that can convert that to a migration too? (I can alter the datatypes when needed).

I have quite a few of these APIs and it will take a lot of time to do that manually so I am wondering whether there's some sort of quick to use converter for such a case.

Thanks!

Comment: You can do that conversion, but this will make the file not be a valid json file anymore. Depending on how that definition is used, this may break your app.

Comment: oh yeah, i don't care about that really, I just want to directly insert that into a rails statement, like a create() It's basically for utility, just to quickly convert those without having to do it manually in my code.

Comment: Something like `Model.create(JSON.parse(json_string))`?

Comment: actually this seems to be working yeah, nice, I thought it would be using the ":" symbol but it does use =>, cool :D

Comment: I think you're just confused here. The JSON style syntax (`{ foo: 'bar' }`) for writing hashes introduced in Ruby 2 is simply a way of writing hash literals with symbols for keys. Hashes are not actually stored as json style or hashrocket style. And when you inspect a hash ruby will always display it with hashrockets.

Comment: If you actually want to parse JSON and get `{:hello => 'there', ....}` you have to parse it with the symbolize keys option as JSON.parse creates string keys. Not that it actually matters as the `.create` method doesn't care.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use

```
Model.create(JSON.parse(json_string))
```